# Get Username in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have 2 user chat with each other.Now I want to get both of 2 username to insert in database with these field `"id", "content","user1","user2"`.

Html

```
<div class="message-wrap col-lg-8">
    <div class="msg-wrap">
        <div class="media msg " id="messages">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="send-wrap ">

        <textarea class="form-control send-message" rows="3" placeholder="Write a reply..." id="messageInput"></textarea>


    </div>
    <form class="form-inline" id="messageForm">
     {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Gửi" id="sendMess" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Server Side:

```
//require module
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

//crate instance of express and http
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );
//listen to socket from server
var io = socket.listen( server );

//when client connect to server console.log
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );
    //when we receive message 
    client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message +' avatar' +data.avatar );

        io.sockets.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message,avatar:data.avatar } );
    });
});

server.listen( 8080 );
```

Client side

```
var socket=io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );

$("#messageForm").submit(function(){
    var username=$("#welcome_user").text();
    var msg=$("#messageInput").val();
    var avatar=$("#user_avatar").attr('src');
    var token=$("input[name='_token']").val();
    socket.emit('message',{name:username,message:msg,avatar:avatar});
    $.ajax({
        url: "/saveMessage",
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: username, message: msg,_token:token },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.mess);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

socket.on('message' ,function(data){
    var actualContent=$("#messages").html();
    var cur_time=new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    var newContent='<span class="pull-left" href="#">'+'<img class="media-object" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;float: left;margin-right: 10px;" src='+data.avatar+'>'+'</span><div class="media-body"><h5 class="media-heading username">'+data.name+'</h5><small class="col-lg-10 message_content">'+data.message+'</small></div>';
    $("#messages").append(newContent);
});
```

By doing this I can get only 1 user.So how can I do that using socket.io.
Thanks for help.Best regard.

Comment: Well where is the server code, and what's the actual problem? What do you mean by "I can get only 1 user". Why? How?

Comment: @AndreyPopov i just update my code.I mean that when 2 user chat with each other,i want to get both their username to insert to database